# Azure Functions retrieve Cosmos DB binding taking too long

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, response-time

I have a Azure Functions set up to retrieve some containers in my cosmos DB but the response time is between 3000 - 5000ms. Only one of the containers has 1000 items, and the others are less than 100 and the performance is already so bad. How can I improve this back down to < 50ms?

This is my azure function

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    
    var users = context.bindings.users
    var items = context.bindings.items
    var userHistory = context.bindings.userHistory

};
```

and these are my bindings

```
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "schedule": "0 */15 * * * *",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "timerTrigger"
    },
    {
      "name": "userHistory",
      "databaseName": "xxx",
      "collectionName": "UserHistory",
      "connectionStringSetting": "xxx",
      "partitionKey": "/userhistory",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.interval=15 ORDER BY c.upn",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "cosmosDB"
    },
    {
      "name": "items",
      "databaseName": "xxx",
      "collectionName": "Items",
      "connectionStringSetting": "xxx",
      "partitionKey": "/tickers",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "cosmosDB"
    },
    {
      "name": "users",
      "databaseName": "xxx",
      "collectionName": "Users",
      "connectionStringSetting": "xxx",
      "partitionKey": "/users",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT c.upn, c.cash, c.items FROM c,
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "cosmosDB"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you are trying to fetch all documents via query `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.interval=15 ORDER BY c.upn`  which is doing cross partition query. Is it possible to fetch only specific partition data by adding the where clause in the query?

Comment: Did You check it is CosmosDb connection issue or maybe is it a Function problem? Double-check Functions SLA. Isn't it a cold start (a rare executed function so it needs to initialize lots of infrastructures)?

It is not a cross partition problem because cross partition problem occurs only if data exceeds partition size limit (5GB default). Cross partition query problem exists if there is more than one physical partition